# c++ curly braces and comments

Tags: c++, coding-style, comments, braces

C++ begginer here.
I'm struggling a bit to get what's the best practice for curly braces + //comments.

I see that for functions comments above the definition provide Visual Studio inspection utility by hovering the mouse on them anywhere.
But when it comes to if statements and the sorts, I can't figure out what will be best more helpful in upcoming projects

So, between

```
if (condition) {  // comment
    do something();
}
```

or

```
// comment
if (condition) {  
    do something();
}
```

or

```
if (condition) // comment
{  
    do something();
}
```

or even the following one (to use the  that usually useless newline)

```
if (condition)
{  // comment
    do something();
}
```

there no clear "Ah this one is better because of xyz", to me yet.

Thank you for any foresight!

Cheers

Comment: As you have observed, it makes no difference to the actual semantics, so this question can really only be answered with personal opinions; this is explicitly off topic. In reality, just *having* meaningful comments somewhere near the code they apply to is better than most people manage.

Comment: @BoBTFish
This is not a fair assumption, since my question is concerned about future code expansion and what will be the practice that will give me less trouble and more agility over many files.

Comment: I did notice that for variables being set comments either above or bellow provides Visual Studio inspection of them.

Comment: Code formatting styles are in general regarded as just opinion, which is off-topic. But I guess there is one possible way to be on-topic: a question on tool supports on coding formatting styles. e.g. How an IDE interpret comments or help formatting.

Comment: @NickyC You think it's worth I change the question so it fits that? Just lock it to Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example may be handled differently depending on whether comment is applied to condition or to bock. First case typically indicates that condition may be rather complex and it would make sense to refactor it into separate variable or to separate method with proper naming so comment (if it is still necessary) will be applied to this variable or method. Second case typically indicates that you are doing something complex in that block and it would make sense to refactor block into separate method with proper naming so comment (if it is still necessary again) will be applied to this method. Notice that introduction of separate entities with proper names often completely removes need for a comment.

As for curly braces there is no common approach, you can probably encounter all kind of crazy braces placement. Some people will even defend such pluralism. I prefer to place matching braces aligned - either horizontally (that is on the same line) or vertically (that is with same indentation) when content does not fit into one line. And this rule is applied to all braces, not just to curly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working on individual/personal projects then any of the above ways will work fine. However, I personally will say that I think an if statement looks more readable if they're written out like:-

```
if ( a > 10 )
{
    std::cout << "a is above 10" << std::endl;
}
```

Or for a single line:-

```
if ( a > 10 )
    std::cout << "a is above 10" << std::endl;
```

Unless when working in groups or organizations, in such case rules/standards/conventions may need to be followed.